# Laravel 9 - Read/Get Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm beginning a full project with Laravel 9, I'm creating a users management page.

I would like to read all informations from 'users' table except the password.

```
    public function AffichageGestion()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('usersManagement.userManagement')->with('users', $users);
    }
```

This is my code for the moment, I select all informations but I don't want this. I want all informations except the password. How can I do that please ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Write the query to return only what you want [See the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, you can do like this.

```
public function AffichageGestion()
{
    $users = User::all([ 'name', 'email']); // except password
    return view('usersManagement.userManagement')->with('users', $users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use makeHidden function.

```
public function AffichageGestion()
    {
        $users = User::get()->makeHidden(['password']);
        return view('usersManagement.userManagement')->with('users', $users);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your query to hide the password from response is a terrible idea since Laravel models include a default property.

Read it [Hiding Attributes From JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Add below line in `users` model

```
  protected $hidden = ['password'];
```

and password will be hidden.